# A vector field over a complex riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let be a complex riemannian manifold $(M,g,J)$. Is the following canonical vector field studied ?
$$
X_J = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}  \nabla^{LC}_{e_i}e_i +\nabla^{LC}_{Je_i}Je_i+ J[e_i,Je_i],
$$
with the $(e_i)$, an orthonormal basis and $\nabla^{LC}$, the Levi-Civita connection. It seems indeed that $\nabla_e^{LC}f + \nabla_{Jf}^{LC} Je + J[e,Jf]$ is a tensor in $(e,f)$. If the manifold is Kaehler, it can be reduced to the torsion, so zero. We can also introduce a tensor with a quaternionic structure :
$$
T_H (X,Y)=\nabla_{IX}IY + \nabla_{JY}JX + K[IX,JY]
$$
with $IJK=-1$, the quaternionic structure. If it is hyperkaehler, it reduces also to zero torsion.

Comment: Does it have a relationship to the Nijenhuis tensor?

Comment: Another keyword to look for would be "intrinsic torsion", here for the $U(n)$ geometry given by the Hermitian structure.

Comment: The anti-symmetric part of the tensor is exactly the Nijenhuis-Newlander tensor. If it is Kaehler, the pseudo-complex structure is integrable.